# Using SQL stored procedure can we get the following output? or handle it within the code itself?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, sql-server-2012

[image]

[image]

Image 1 is the current data,
Image 2 is the data i need to store into a new table. Thing is i want to combine all the same ITEM_NO and put it as a comma separated value and insert into a new table.

Comment: Which sql it is? oracle , sql server?

Comment: isn't this solved with a simple group by and a concat aggregate function? And do you really need to store it in a new table or would a view suffice?

Comment: @Tschallacka tried but expected output not correct and need to insert into a new table. Pragmatically i have done what i expected and want to know whether i can achieve the same by using SP.

Comment: you shouldn't store this kind of data in the database, cause it violates first normalform see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form . You should store your data in at least 3NF if you not want to get into serious trouble... You need really good reasons to violate 3NF...

Comment: @Radagast81 yes it is but we don't have another choice because after changing data like this client get rid of the performance issue which they have reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst I don't think storing data like this is a good idea at all (see what others have said in the comments) it is possible by doing:

```
SELECT REFERENCE_NO, 
       ITEM_NO, 
       ROLES = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + ENTITY_ROLE 
                      FROM dbo.MyTable AS p2
                      WHERE p2.ITEM_NO = p.ITEM_NO 
                      ORDER BY ENTITY_ROLE
                      FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM dbo.MyTable AS p
GROUP BY REFERENCE_NO, ITEM_NO
ORDER BY ITEM_NO;
```

A demo of this in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0f61/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.